# Button with same behavior in two distinct components

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a button that changes image depending on its state, start / pause and starts a time count.

I can run the button and run it on two different components, however, the button's image / status doesn't appear, it's just showing me the time :(

How can I solve this?

I successfully run the button on the services component as shown in the image

When I go to the over component, I want to get the exact same state of the button in the services component ... but the button doesn't change state :( This is my problem

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 10%">
    <div class="btn-group" dropdown>

        <button id="button-basic" dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn ">
   <img style="width: 35px;" *ngIf="currentState=='pause'" src="https://img.icons8.com/carbon-copy/100/000000/play-button-circled.png" >
                 <img style="width: 35px;" *ngIf="currentState=='start'" src="https://img.icons8.com/cute-clipart/64/000000/stop-squared.png" >
    </button>
        <ul id="dropdown-basic" *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="button-basic">
            <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="currentState=='pause'" routerLinkActive="active"
                    (click)="currentState='start'; startTimer()">Start</a></li>
            <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="currentState=='start'" routerLinkActive="active"
                    (click)="currentState='pause'; pauseTimer()">Stop</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            <span>{{servicesService.fetchDisplay()}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modified your code, maintain the state in the service so it can be shared.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7mccwr?file=src/app/about/about.component.ts)